# ROS Jade compatible with ROS-Industrial Hydro?

Tags: ros-jade, ros-hydro, ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

is it possible to pair ROS-Industrial Hydro (which is the latest) with ROS Jade / Ros Kinetic Kame.
I am currently on Ubuntu and would like to know if i have to downgrade my OS if i want to use ROS-I.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232797/ros-jade-compatible-with-ros-industrial-hydro?/) by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:\

> ROS-Industrial Hydro (which is the latest) [..]

Can you tell us where you found this? Not all packages have been released on Indigo/Jade, but Hydro is certainly not the last ROS release supported by ROS-Industrial (although that is an ambiguous statement in any case).

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-04-25**:
It says here: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install that Ros Industrial's latest release is Hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is it possible to pair ROS-Industrial Hydro (which is the latest) with ROS Jade / Ros Kinetic Kame. I am currently on Ubuntu and would like to know if i have to downgrade my OS if i want to use ROS-I.

The page you link to in your comment does indeed refer to the Hydro release as the *latest version of ROS-Industrial*. That page is outdated however (reported on the issue tracker as [ros_industrial_issues#40](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_industrial_issues/issues/40)). A number of packages in ROS-Industrial have since been released into Indigo (and `industrial_core` also has a Jade release). Kinetic is **not** officially supported (but see below).

As a bit of clarification: there are essentially two ways to use the packages in ROS-Industrial:

1. installing the `deb` packages built by the ROS buildfarm: this would use the normal `sudo apt-get install ros-...` command.
2. cloning the relevant repositories into a catkin workspace and building the packages from source with `catkin_make`.

Option 1 is the easiest, but requires the packages to have been released using the ROS buildfarm. Two ways to verify this: look for a `Released` badge under the *Package Summary* section on the wiki page of the package (see [industrial_core](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_core) fi), or check the various *release status* pages provided by the OSRF ([Indigo](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html), [Jade](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html) and [Kinetic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html)).

If a package hasn't been released for a particular ROS release, it may still work when built from source (option 2, also referred to on the [Industrial/Install](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install#Industrial.2BAC8-Install.2BAC8-Hydro.Source_Installation_.28Recommended_for_Developers.29) page). For packages released into Indigo, building from source under Jade will most likely always work (differences are minor). For Kinetic this may not be the case (note that as of writing this (2016-04-25), Kinetic hasn't been released completely yet).

Building from source requires a catkin workspace and some additional work to make sure all required dependencies are installed. Note that this would only build the ROS-Industrial packages from source, *not* ROS itself. Some packages have instructions that show how to do this, see [fanuc_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver?distro=jade) for Jade for an example.

Do please report any issues you run into when building from source on (un)supported platforms, and we'll make sure to address them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cschindlbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26691/cschindlbeck/) on 2016-04-25**:
Thanks for your thorough answer!
In particular, i am interested in using the kuka_experimental package. However, there is no package summary. Since you are one of the developer, can you comment on the follwowing:
Will kuka_experimental work with ROS Jade / Indigo releases?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:
I've actually added a wiki page for `kuka_experimental` this morning, see [wiki/kuka_experimental](http://wiki.ros.org/kuka_experimental). The basic robot support packages should work under Indigo & Jade. The `rsi_hw_interface` should also work, but I haven't tested it personally.